# How to build AccountManager around Android killing the app process

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have an app where users can log in and browse the app through several activities. To do that, I have an `AccountManager` set up in my main activity, the one that is always at the bottom of the activity stack - let's call it `MainActivity`. There are other activities that depend on the user being logged in, and that use the `AccountManager` instance that's in `MainActivity`.

Assuming a user is in an activity stack with such an activity `ActivityB` on top, and `MainActivity` on bottom. When the user leaves the app and does other stuff, Android might decide to terminate the app for RAM/CPU usage reasons. When the user then reopens the app, `ActivityB` will restart and show up, but `MainActivity` will remain terminated (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) under Saving Activity State). This is annoying, because the `AccountManager` instance will not be remade either, until the user decides to return to `MainActivity` - causing the functionality of `ActivityB` to be broken.

Unfortunately, I can't use any `Context` instance for `AccountManager.get(Context)`, because I need to use the function `AccountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener` which creates a need for the specified `Context` instance to remain instantiated, as also described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#get(android.content.Context)).

Is there a nice way to go about this? Can I get an instance of `AccountManager` without having to rely on `MainActivity` being instantiated, possibly using a separate static class / singleton?

Comment: but AccountManager has already static method get ... did you at least read the AccountManager class documentation? ... Or you are writing about your own AccountManager class, not connected with the one from android's API? then it is not possible to answer without knowladge about what this class is doing

Comment: Oops, should've added some info maybe: I'm using the normal AccountManager class, not my own. I can't just use the AccountManager.get function from anywhere, because it needs a Context. The documentation says that "The Context will be used as long as the AccountManager is active, so make sure to use a Context whose lifetime is commensurate with any listeners registered to addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(OnAccountsUpdateListener, Handler, boolean) or similar methods.", so I'm hesitant to just use any context - knowing that something like `ActivityB` might be terminated while using the app.

Comment: hten whre is the problem ... you can obtain `AccountManager` instance whenever you have valid `Context`

Comment: Alright, so I don't have to worry about the `Context` not being eternal, or bound to the `OnAccountsUpdateListner`, as stated in the documentation?

Comment: ok without `addOnAccountsUpdatedListener` it was not clear why you bother about given Context... Now the problem is more complicated

Comment: Ah I see the confusion now, my bad! Updated the main question

Comment: As it seems that you need it for a whole app lifetime  then you make use of own implementation of Application class (personally i don't like it) and use ApplicationContext ... edit: question is do you really need `OnAccountsUpdateListner`

Comment: I guess I can try without `OnAccountsUpdateListener` and see what happens. It is not originally my code base, so I'm hesitant, but it's worth a shot. Thanks a lot for your help!